# loki: "error at least one label pair is required per stream"

Tags: logging, grafana-loki

I am running loki, pomtrail, grafana locally in docker per [these instructions](https://github.com/grafana/loki/tree/main/production)

When I try to run the following test to send data directly to loki:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST --data '{ "streams": [ { "labels": { "job": "randomjob" }, "entries": [{ "ts": "2021-10-12T16:13:06.801064Z", "line": "TEST!" }] } ] }' http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push
```

I get the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 12:09:26 GMT
Content-Length: 53

error at least one label pair is required per stream
```

Why isn't if finding the label?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format of the label pairs should be (for an old endpoint `/api/prom/push`) and it works:

```
"labels": "{job=\"randomjob\"}"
```

E.g.:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -s "172.30.11.21:3100/api/prom/push" --data-raw   '{"streams": [
  { 
      "labels": "{job=\"randomjob\"}", 
      "entries": [
          { 
              "ts": "2021-11-13T19:55:51.801064-00:00", 
              "line": "TEST!" 
          }
      ] 
  }
]
```

}'

For a new endpoint `/loki/api/v1/push` it seems need to change `labels` field to `stream`:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -s "172.30.11.21:3100/loki/api/v1/push" --data-raw '{"streams": [{ "stream": {"job": "randomjob"}, "values": [["1636841990000000000",  "TEST!" ]] }] }]}'
```

Comment: omg that fixed it. So i just needed backslashes??! I'm getting a new error now `loghttp.PushRequest.Streams: []*loghttp.Stream: Skip: do not know how to skip: 92, error found in #10 byte of ...` but this clearly fixed the label pair error so accepting answer!

Comment: Well, yes, for the old endpoint you need to use `labels` value as a single string, apart it contains the json-object, and then you need to escape internal double quotes.

For the new endpoint the fields are different: `stream` and `values`.